# What is the most intuitive layout for a class that manages pointers to different types?

Tags: c++

I have a class that manages a map of strings and pointers as such:

```
class DebugTab
{
public:
    void pushItem(std::string&& name, std::unique_ptr<DebugItem> item);
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<DebugItem>> items_;
};
```

The pointers should be able to point to different types so to achieve this I made this simple abstract class:

```
class DebugItem
{
public:
    virtual std::string asString() = 0;
};
```

And then made a few derived classes for fundamental types:

```
class DebugInt : public DebugItem
{
public:
    DebugInt(int& i) : i_(i) {}
    std::string asString() override {return std::to_string(i_);}
private:
    int& i_;
};

class DebugFloat : public DebugItem
{
public:
    DebugFloat(float& f) : f_(f) {}
    std::string asString() override {return std::to_string(f_);}
private:
    float& f_;
};

class DebugString : public DebugItem
{
public:
    DebugString(std::string& s) : s_(s) {}
    std::string asString() override {return s_;}
private:
    std::string& s_;
};
```

My idea was that the person using `DebugTab` would create the item with the correct class on the heap using 'new' and then pass the pointer to `pushItem` like this:

```
DebugTab tab;

int var1;
float var2;
std::string var3;

tab.pushItem("var1", std::move(std::make_unqiue<DebugInt>(var1)));
tab.pushItem("var2", std::move(std::make_unique<DebugFloat>(var2)));
tab.pushItem("var3", std::move(std::make_unique<DebugString>(var3)));
```

I'm not very satisfied with this solution. I feel that it just isn't very intuitive to pass a heap pointer to a class that tracks already created variables.

Is there a better, simpler way of doing all of this that comes to mind, or is the system I have now sufficient?

Comment: "*The pointers should be able to point to different types*" ... why? Also, who is managing the `unique_ptr` that this map receives? The value_type of the map isn't `unique_ptr`, so someone has to be holding on to ownership of that object, yes?

Comment: @NicolBolas The value_type of the map being raw pointers was not intended, I have fixed it now. As to your other question, I should have phrased that part a little differently. Obviously pointers in a map can't point to different types, what I meant is that I need to be able to refer to different types using the pointers.

Comment: Without knowing more about how these are used it is hard to have an opinion.  But `std::variant` may be worth looking at here and storing your debug items as first class values.

Comment: Since your base class only has asString, why not just have a map of strings (as you won’t be able to access the contained int, float, whatever from the base class)? Otherwise create a template derived class from your base class.

Comment: Will DebugString leak without a virtual destructor in DebugBase?

Comment: Minor point: don't write `f(std::move(g()))`, use `f(g())` instead when `g()` is a prvalue as in the code above. It's simpler and even (slightly) more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically you can skip allocating them at callsite...

```cpp
template<class T>
struct DebugConcrete: DebugItem {
    T &t;
    std::string asSring() const override {
        return std::to_string(t);
    }
};

class DebugTab {
    template<class T>
    void pushItem(std::string name, T &item) {
        items_.emplace(std::move(name),
                 std::make_unique<DebugConcrete<T>>(item));
    }
};
#define pushItem(...) pushItem(#__VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    int i;
    DebugTab tab;
    tab.pushItem(i);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t tab.pushItem(i) have a string parameter first?

Comment: @DS_London no it shouldn't, at least not this one.

Comment: Thanks! Just a few questions: 1. What does the line under the DebugTab class defintion do? I'm not super familiar with #define statements. 2. How are you calling pushItem with just one argument, didn't you define it to take two? 3. How would I do this with strings, since to_string doesn't have an overload for strings?

Comment: 1. actually allows for 2.: with `pushItem` thus `#define`d, `tab.pushItem(i)` eventually expands into `tab.pushItem("i", i)`. For 3., you'll need to define an explicit specialization `template<> struct DebugConcrete<std::string>;`.